# How to link an Adobe AIR3 Native Extension for iOS against an iOS framework?

Tags: ios, linker, air, native

I’m working on an app with an AIR3 iOS native extension that uses Accelerate.framework

Followed the first steps mentioned in the tutorials, successfully created an .ane file etc.

When I run the final packaging command (adt -package -target ipa-test ...), I get the following errors:

```
ld warning: unexpected srelocation type 9
ld warning: unexpected srelocation type 9
```

... (repeating several times)

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_vDSP_vsdiv", referenced from: ...
  "_vDSP_vsmul", referenced from: ...
```

... several more like this

```
ld: symbol(s) not found
Compilation failed while executing : ld64
```

I guess this is because when I created the .a file in xcode, it couldn’t really link it statically to the Accelerate.framework.

I suppose I need to tell adt to link it somehow? Probably in the phase I’m creating the .ane file? Or maybe I should change my extension.xml file?

No idea. Couldn’t really find it...

Please advise.

**UPDATE:** This seems like a bug on the Adobe side specifically with Accelerate.framework. I'll keep updating here in case other guys stumble upon this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest Flex 4.6 SDK. If that doesn't solve it, ensure you have specified the Apple iOS SDK correctly under the Native Extensions tab of your Apple iOS build packaging in your project settings. It should be

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk

if you installed Xcode into the default folder

Answer (score 2):

I've had this "srelocation" error, because the included libraries (in my case AudioToolBox/ OpenAL) were treated as shared libraries by XCode: They were not included in my library build (even when it's static). I've had to set "Enable Linking With Shared Libraries" under Build Settings to NO, and then the errors have been gone. Maybe this will solve your problem too...

Comment: very interesting... didn't know about this option and it seems like a good direction... However, when I set it to NO I get a build error: 
`Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1`

Comment: OK, tried again with LLVM 3.0 and it worked, and indeed it solves the srelocation warnings, so thank you for this. But it doesn't solve my original problem...

Comment: I've been trying this with AddressBook framework, but It doesn't work for me. Have you guys tried this with AddressBook framework. Much Appreciate.

Comment: @kblau: this didn't remove my 12000+ srelocation warnings with GoogleAdMob, and also made the app crash at the first line of the app delegate (this is iphone now).